# Print Pandas Unique Rows by Column Condition

Tags: pandas, max, unique

I am trying to print the rows whereby a data condition is met in a pandas DF based on the unique values in the DF. For example, I have data that looks like this:

DF:

```
site  temp  month  day
A     15    7      18
A     11    6      12
A     22    9       3
B      9    4      23
B      3    2      11
B     -1    5      18
```

I need the result to print the rows where the max in the 'temp' column occurs such as this for the final result:
A  15
B   9

I have tried this but it is not working correctly:

```
for i in DF['site'].unique():
    print(DF.temp.max())
```

I get the same answer of:

```
22
22
```

but the answer should be:

```
site  temp  month  day
A     22    9      3
B      9    4     23
```

thank you!

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to include 2 key "date" columns that I need to print with the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
df.groupby('site', as_index=False).max()
```

Output:

```
  site  temp
0    A    22
1    B     9
```

---

In case you want to use a `for` loop:

```
for i in df['site'].unique():
    print(df.loc[df['site'].eq(i), 'temp'].max())
```

Output:

```
22
9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('site').max()
```

output:

```
        temp    month   day
site            
A       22      9       18
B       9       5       23
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us do `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`

```
df = df.sort_values('temp',ascending=False).drop_duplicates('site')
Out[190]: 
  site  temp  month  day
2    A    22      9    3
3    B     9      4   23
```